Random per island gives different color to every face
Am I misunderstanding what an island is? When I press L, it selects all connected geometry which is as expected. But islands seem to be something else entirely?

Here's the .blend file 

L selects entire island, so it looks like a bug.

Apparently the sharp edges separate islands. It might be a bug I don't know... In Geometry Nodes each crayon here will be one island... https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.1/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html?utm_source=blender-4.1.1#bpy-types-shadernodenewgeometry *"Random per Island Cycles Only
A random value for each connected component (island) of the mesh."*


@MarkusvonBroady Thanks! I've unsharped edges. Please make an answer so I can mark it as answered.

No it depends on Object Mode/Edit Mode :D

I can't reproduce this behavior for a new object... Maybe someone else will figure out what's going here (maybe it's just some bug). MARKING ALL EDGES SHARP FIXES IT TOO :D

@MarkusvonBroady I just looked into this since this question appeared in the the Review Queues. It seems as if the simple explanation is, the sharp edges work in Cycles like an edge split for the Random Per Island output. Faces isolated from others by sharp edges are treated as island, faces having at least one smooth edge form an island with the face(s) that share those smooth edges. This is true as long as not all edges are sharp - somehow if each single face is isolated by sharp edges, suddenly Blender treats all connected faces as an island and ignores the splitting by sharp edges.

@MarkusvonBroady And this happens when the object is set to Shade Smooth, not Shade Flat. Flat shading is basically treating all edges as sharp edges, so it behaves like mentioned above: when all of the edges are sharp, Blender treats them altogether as an island. A special case is using Auto Smooth, the Smooth by Angle modifier which is then added to the object can create different variations of this weird behaviour, depending on the chosen Angle and on enabling or disabling Ignore Sharpness.

It seems to be a bug for blender 4.2.3. I have no sharp edges (blue-marked edges), but turning off the Smooth by Angle modifier fixes the problem. It appears that this modifier tears the mesh apart. The same issue occurs if I mark a polygon's edges as Sharp.
I copied and pasted the same object into a 3.6 and 4.3 scenes and checked it there; everything works as expected, no any issue with sharp edges or smooth by angle modifier in these versions of blender.

I opened it in my Blender 4.3, there was a problem with sharp edges and the downloaded file has no Smooth by Angle modifier. The problem/bug or whatever seems to be a bit more complex. You can get different variations of incorrect islands depending on whether you mark only the horizontal loops sharp, or just the tips, or the vertical edges but only the top or the bottom horizontal loops etc. and all completely without the use of a Smooth by Angle modifier. Only if shaded flat or all edges sharp or none of the edges sharp it works exactly as expected.

I just realized, it is actually not more complex, it is much easier... see my comments below the question. In older versions I can reproduce this behaviour with the Edge Split modifier, but I actually wasn't aware that the modifier could separate the pieces - but since shading is always last in line after all modifiers, this makes sense.
